# Draw objects graph in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have to draw something like a calendar. 
I have a table where at top we see days and at left we see drivers' names.
And in a cell we see how many hours he works. 
How to draw this table?

Also I need ability right clicking open driver's card.
How to do this also?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Mon" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Tue" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="Wen" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="Thu" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="Fri" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Driver X" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Driver Y" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Driver Z" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=DriverX.MonHours}" />
```

Check Micheal Snow's blog for the right clicking at http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/04/23/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-3-mouse-right-clicks/